# How data goes to the other side in maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian, bayes-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I am reading the book Mathematics for Machine learning and I am a bit confused with maximum likelihood estimation. I understand that the likelihood is the probability of get certain observations $x$, given a set of parameters $\theta$:
$$p(x|\theta)$$
So, find a maximum value implies that you have chosen the set of parameters for which data is more likely to have been measured. But then book gives an example for linear regression where it assumes a gaussian likelihood function and it says that it is:
$$p(y_n|\mathbf{x}_n, \mathbf{\theta}) = \mathcal{N}(y_n|\mathbf{x}_n^\intercal\mathbf{\theta}, \sigma^2)$$
What I dont understand is how data $\mathbf{x}_n$ now is in the other side of $|$. I think that $\mathbf{x}_n$ is part of the data observed, along with $y_n$, and $\mathbf{\theta}$ the parameters that should be on the right side of the conditional probability.

Comment: In regression, you observe two dimensions: $(x_i, y_i)$ and you model the relationship between the two as $y=f(x, \theta)+\epsilon$. In statistics, $x$ is the explanatory variable and $y$ is the response variable. Machine learning has come up with new names like “features” for $x$. In any case we model $Y$ as a RV conditional on the values $X$. So picking optimal $\theta$ can depend on the data $X=x$.